# Frequency and Percentage in dataframe.groupby with sort

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have a Pandas dataframe, where the interesting feature for me is called `Tenure` (one of the predictors) and a column named `Churn` (the label, string of '0' and '1').

```
col1    col2    ... Tenure  ... Churn
val_1   ...         5           0
val_i   ...         ...         label_i
val_n   ...         36          1
```

Now I want to produce a dataframe with these values:

```
Tenure  Churned Churn_Rate
5       51      15.31
...     ...     ...
36      16      21.98
```

The data is grouped by `Tenure`, and `Churned` is the frequency of values '1', and `Churn_Rate` is the percentage of such occurrence for every `Tenure` value.

So far this is what I've done, but I am getting a tuple instead.

```
churn_per_tenure = grs_df_main.groupby(['Tenure']).apply(lambda x: ((x['Churn'] == '1').sum(), x['Churn'].count()))
```

Also, how do I sort this output by: `Tenure`, `Churned` or `Churn_Rate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
grs_df_main = pd.DataFrame({'Tenure':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3],
                            'Churn': ['0','1','1','1','0','0','0']})

print(grs_df_main)
   Tenure Churn
0       1     0
1       1     1
2       1     1
3       2     1
4       2     0
5       2     0
6       3     0
```

If want only `rate` column you can use syntactig sugar - `groupby` by `boolean mask` with `Series` `grs_df_main['Tenure']` and aggregate `mean`:

```
churn_per_tenure = ((grs_df_main['Churn'] == '1').groupby(grs_df_main['Tenure'])
                                                 .mean()
                                                 .reset_index(name='Churn_Rate'))
print (churn_per_tenure)
   Tenure  Churn_Rate
0       1    0.666667
1       2    0.333333
2       3    0.000000
```

For all columns use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with `lambda` function:

```
f = lambda x: (x == '1').sum()
f.__name__ = 'Churned'
churn_per_tenure = grs_df_main.groupby(['Tenure'])['Churn'].agg([f, 'count']).reset_index()
churn_per_tenure['Churn_Rate'] = churn_per_tenure['Churned'] / churn_per_tenure.pop('count')
print (churn_per_tenure)
   Tenure  Churned  Churn_Rate
0       1        2    0.666667
1       2        1    0.333333
2       3        0    0.000000
```

If want also `count` column remove `pop` function:

```
churn_per_tenure['Churn_Rate'] = churn_per_tenure['Churned'] / churn_per_tenure['count']
print (churn_per_tenure)
   Tenure  Churned  count  Churn_Rate
0       1        2      3    0.666667
1       2        1      3    0.333333
2       3        0      1    0.000000
```